# monthly checklist on msaccess

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of the form show below.My intention is to create a monthly checklist.

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id          | mem_id         | month_code      | type            |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      1      |  1             |     Jan         |    to           |   
|      2      |  2             |     Feb         |    t            |   
|      3      |  1             |     Feb         |    to           |
|      4      |  3             |     Jan         |    o            |
|      5      |  1             |     Mar         |    o            |   
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

The query used is

```
SELECT distinct(mem_id) as Member,
(SELECT type FROM test where mem_id=Member and month_code='Jan') as Jan,
(SELECT type FROM test where mem_id=Member and month_code='Feb') as Feb,
(SELECT type FROM test where mem_id=Member and month_code='Mar') as Mar
FROM  test
```

The desired output is

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| mem_id      | Jan            | Feb             | Mar             |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      1      |  to            |     to          |    o            |   
|      2      |                |     t           |                 |   
|      3      |  o             |                 |                 |   
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

My problem however is that the code works fine on `mysql` but on `msaccess` I get a pop up of an input box asking me to enter the value of parameter `Member`. How can I have the correct output in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation instead :

```
select mem_id,
       max(iif(month_code = 'Jan', type)) as Jan,
       max(iif(month_code = 'Feb', type)) as Feb,
       max(iif(month_code = 'Mar', type)) as Mar
from test t
group by mem_id;
```

For your query, the name `Member` doesn't exists in `test` table so, `access` considered it as `parameter`.

So, you probably need `mem_id` instead :

```
SELECT t.mem_id as Member,
      (SELECT t1.type FROM test as t1 where t1.mem_id = t.mem_id and t1.month_code='Jan') as Jan,
      (SELECT t1.type FROM test as t1 where t1.mem_id = t.mem_id and t1.month_code='Feb') as Feb,
      (SELECT t1.type FROM test as t1 where t1.mem_id = t.mem_id and t1.month_code='Mar') as Mar
FROM test as t
GROUP BY t.mem_id;
```

The only problem is that with your version is, if one  `mem_id` has duplicate `type`s for same `month_code` then it will throw `subquery` error.

So, you need `top` clause in `subquery`.